# opencv haartraining has stopped working

Tags: opencv, training-data, haar-classifier

i have 585 face positive image

and i use this code for make my vector

```
createsamples.exe -info positive/info.txt -vec vector/facevector.vec -num 585 -w 24 -h 24
```

and i use this code for haartraining

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_haartraining.exe -data cascades -vec vector/facevector.vec -bg negative/bg.txt -npos 525 -nneg 1225 -nstages 20 -nsplits 2 -nonsym -minhitrate 0.95 -maxfalsealarm 0.4 -mem 1024 -mode ALL -w 24 -h 24 PAUSE
```

> ```
> -npos its 525
> ```
>
> I read it must be 0.9 * positive image in vector
>
> -nneg its  1225
>
> I read its must be 2:1 negative to positive

now when i start haartrainng its stop on some stage and give me opencv_haartraining has stop working

like this image [image]

Answer (score 0):

if opencv_haartraining.exe is starting to build the cascade (doesn't stop at 1st stage) I believe that the stop is due to settings or data.
while I was using opencv_traincascade.exe (should be an older version of opencv_haartraining.exe) I used 80% of the positive samples (you are using 90%) 
and also noticed that at small positive sample quantity (less than 500) the execution may also suddenly stop.
I would suggest you to try augmenting the number of positives and use 80% of them.
hope that helps

Comment: thank you its work ^___^ ,,, can i use more than 2:1 negative to positive image like 4:1 ?

Comment: oh ... its complete 2 stage after third stage and on 7 stage its stopped again

Comment: using 4:1 negative to positive is not restricted as far as I know, still may result in accuracy loss (being not a software problem but a data set one) . Please show a printscreen of the stopped exec

Comment: its like the image above in my question ... now i change my haartraining.exe to another program maybe its older and its didn't stop

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, the parameter npos must be less than the pos samples you have; so is the parameter nneg.

You can use pos samples you have * 0.8 as the parameter npos, so is nneg.

It is very useful.

Comment: And be careful that, the neg sample must be bigger than the pos samples.